# Remove repetition from permutation

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

If there x number of objects, and y number of possible colors I can paint each of the objects.  How do I count each unique permutation of objects and colors, e.g. A = { α, β, γ } and B = { red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet }, then below is one permutation:

```
  | red    | orange | yellow | green  | blue   | indigo | violet |
α |        | x      |        |        |        |        |        |
β | x      |        |        |        |        |        |        |
γ | x      |        |        |        |        |        |        |
```

and so on...

I know that counting permutations on a single dimension, i.e. the number of unique permutations of all the colors is 7!, and the number of permutations of colored objects if 3! in the given example.

How do I calculate the **unique** permutations of the two sets (object, colors)?

Is it simply the case that I should apply the binomial theorem as "y choose x".  In our example: "1,000 colors, choose 3" - or is this incorrect?

Comment: This is far more fundamental than "permutations" or "binomial coefficients."  This relies on the [Rule of Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  Choose what color you paint the first object.  You have $k$ choices where $k$ is the number of colors.  Then choose what color you paint the second object.  You again have $k$ choices.  Continue until you've painted the final $n$'th object.  Multiplying the number of options available at each step gives the total count.

Comment: As an aside, these are not "*permutations*" so don't call them that.  Reserve the word permutations to explicitly only refer to bijective functions from a set to itself or to refer to strings over an alphabet where each letter appears exactly once (*a way of quickly visualizing such a bijective function*).  The objects you are technically counting here are functions/mappings from the set of objects to the set of colors.

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz - it's simpler than I thought. But tell me: what if the order of the selection mattered - do you know what technique I would using for counting the possible outcomes in that case?

Comment: If the order of selection matters, you might count the orders before counting the paintings.  If you have seven objects you can paint three colors, there are $7!$ orders to paint them and $3^7$ ways to paint, for a total of $7!3^7$ overall.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks Ross, that really helped!